# Cross domain cookie is not working

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I'm trying to read cookies from B.com in A.com

To address this I've added an `script tag` in A.com that **is loaded from B.com**. 
This B.com script is a `PHP` which echo of the cookie that I need.

*B.com/script.php*

```
<? echo 'var mycookie="'.$_COOKIE['myBdotComCookie'].";";?>
```

*A.com page:*

```
...
 <script src="http://B.com/script.php">
 ...
```

*Additional info: myBdotComCookie domain is B.com*

### Problem

This is working fine on iOS Chrome, but not on Linux or Win Chrome.

### Question

Is this technique wrong or iOS Chrome has a bug or Linux and Win Chrome have a bug?

**update**:

Also is working fine on FF, but not working on IE8/9

Comment: not sure if that will help, but have you tried adding `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');` at the top of the B.com/script.php? Also make sure domain always completely matches, i.e. B.com vs www.B.com

Comment: Make sure `Block third-party cookies and site data
Manage exceptions...` isn't checked in your privacy settings.

Comment: @apprentice thanx, I've made those changes but nothing has changed.

Comment: @AlienWebguy magic! that feature fix my problem, thank you. Now, There is any way to get that data on default browsers config? (I saw third-party are blocked by default)

Comment: Safari was the first to do it and it put a huge wrench in our Ad placement efforts. You can use a same-domain proxy and use cURL on the server to fetch what you need and place the cookie from the common domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays third party cookies are blocked by more and more browsers. You cannot really use them anymore for anything which needs to be reliable. The reason is that third party cookies can be used to spy on users browsing history. You can always disable them in the browsers privacy settings. Most browsers don't do this by default but for example Safari does. And apparently some versions on Chrome as well.

If you need to fetch some data reliably from the site on different domain you should look into jsonp requests. They are abstracted by jquery so that you perform them with the same api as the ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying jsonp right now and I'll comment you the result.